# Is that a tool dedicated to accessing rtsp streams over IP?

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, ip, vulnerability-scanners, video

Like `sqlmap` for databases, is there a tool that can find vulnerabilities, try default passwords, etc. for the `rtsp` (VoIP) protocol?

Answer (score 3):

There are [various Metasploit modules](https://www.rapid7.com/db/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rtsp&t=a) that can be used for RTSP depending on the application using this protocol.